# How can I use CDI to produce a Hibernate Session?

Tags: hibernate, session, cdi, entitymanager

I have this Resources class which produces my entityManager as well as a hibernate Session:

```
public class Resources {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public Session produceSession() {
        return em.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
}
```

When I inject the EntityManager inside my EJB Class it works fine, but  using the injected hibernate Session just work at the first time. After this, it's always closed. I think that the CDI worked, but it just inject my dependency once, so I can´t use it.

So, I decided to use this:

> entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)

every time I need a Hibernate Session. For example:

```
return criteria.getExecutableCriteria(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).list();
```

My two questions are: Is there another way to do this? Is it a correct approach?

Hope someone help me here!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some CDI extensions floating around, some of which provide hibernate integration.  Realistically though, this should work fine for you.

However, JPA 2 has a criteria API you may be interested in.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer. I already knew the JPA 2 Criteria, but it's a bit complicated, I mean, more complicated than the Hibernate Criteria. I'm going to keep using that approach and will have a look at those CDI extensions. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: This looks like it's because of the default transaction boundary (and default CDI scope) in your project. By default (meaning without any additional annotations or configuration) the duration of the EntityManager is the duration of a transaction, which happens to be the duration of the method. Also CDI beans w/o a scope annotation are DependentScoped which means they live as long as the parent object containing them. The combination of these two is probably the issue you're hitting.